# JWT token not saved in browser cookies Vite React and node JS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, vite

I'm trying to save JWT token in browser cookies it's work in postman and the cookies shown but when I try in browser cookies not saved why ?

cors MiddleWare:

```
app.use(cors({ origin: 'http://127.0.0.1:5173', credentials: true }));
```

the node JS code:

```
const handelSignUp = async (req, res) => {
    const { email, username, password } = req.body;

    try {
        const existingUser = await UserModel.findOne({ email });

        if (existingUser) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Email already exists' });
        } else {
            const newUser = await UserModel.create({
                email: email,
                username: username,
                password: bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(10)),
            });

            const userDoc = await newUser.save();

            if (userDoc) {
                jwt.sign({
                    email: email,
                    username: username,
                    id: userDoc._id,
                }, secret, {}, (error, token) => {
                    if (error) {
                        throw error;
                    }
                    res.cookie("token", token, {
                        maxAge: 3600000 * 24 * 30 * 3,
                        httpOnly: true,
                        domain: '127.0.0.1:5173',
                    }).json({
                        user: userDoc,
                        token: token
                    });
                });
            }
            else {
                console.log("token not created");
            }

        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(400).json({ error: error });
    }
};
```

I tried to change the domain in vite to localhost also not work